# How to achieve fading opacity on an element?

Tags: css, css-transitions

I know, my question is a bit vague, but before you downvote me, please let me explain:

Im currently learning jQuery and i developed my own coverflow_slider. Its 228 lines long and works pretty fine, currently im working to design it a bit better. Currently, its looking like this:

[image: Current Slider]

This here is my .css for the buttons:

```
.left, .right {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 20;
    background-color: #000;
    height: 100%;
    width: 30px;
    opacity: 0.5;

    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}
```

So now you see the 2 grey stripes at both sides? These are the buttons for left/right. Now i want that they have some kind of transition. It should look like this:

[image: The goal]

The request is probably very simple, i just dont know what i should enter in google to find it out. Im more a php developer and not involved in all this designstuff. I know that this thread will cost me probably 50 reputation because of downvotes, but i guess that worth getting an answer.

Comment: What about css gradients?

Comment: This should help - http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/

Comment: gradient ... i didnt know how they are called.^^ Thanks a lot guys.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a CSS3 background gradient. There are lots of online CSS3 background gradient generators such e.g. http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/. Punching in some parameters (e.g. horizontal, #999999 to #FFFFFF, etc) result in the following:

```css
background: #999999;
background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, #999999 0%, #ffffff 100%);
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, color-stop(0%,#999999), color-stop(100%,#ffffff));
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #999999 0%,#ffffff 100%);
background: -o-linear-gradient(left, #999999 0%,#ffffff 100%);
background: -ms-linear-gradient(left, #999999 0%,#ffffff 100%);
background: linear-gradient(to right, #999999 0%,#ffffff 100%);
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#999999', endColorstr='#ffffff', GradientType=1);
```

Comment: Awesome, really. And no downvotes on my startpost, this is like birthday. Thanks a lot. :)